# PHP Namespace - Declare classes with the same name

Tags: php, oop, class, namespaces

Can a parent php script require two classes, each defined with the same class name.

I know by default this will cause an Error, so i have been looking into namespace. I do not want to hardcode the namespace into the class file as it would be inflexible and depend on the person writing the class, i would prefer to do the following.

```
// Define namespace
require_class('a.class.php');

// Define new namespace
require_class('b.class.php');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to define namespaces in such manner.

See [Defining Namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php):

> Namespaces are declared using the namespace keyword. A file containing a namespace must declare the namespace at the top of the file before any other code - with one exception: the declare keyword.

You can define [multiple namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php) in the same file but the classes within that namespace should be place in this files too.

You may consider [Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) with allowing developers to specify initial `namespace` for classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i've read the manual thats why i am asking the question. I have a Modules/Controller.php that requires 2 files that could have the same class name from different modules, so im a little stuck on the solution..